# Using a bash script to grep an integer and compare it to another

Tags: bash, grep, operator-keyword

I have a bash script to copy files from one location to another if the score within the file is less than 36.

I run this script once a month, and it worked before but now I'm getting the error:

```
line 5: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls $1/*.html`
do
        score=`grep -o -P '(?<=ADJ. SCORE: )-?[0-9]?[0-9]' $f`
        if [ $score -lt 36 ]
                then cp $f $2
        fi
done
```

I'm not sure if the OS matters; I'm using OS X 10.7 and I've troubles in the past with my bash scripts that otherwise work great on Linux boxes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that OSX `grep` supports the `-o` option, or the more advanced regexp you've included. Are you seeing any error messages or are you redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`? `man grep` to confirm available options. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter It does have the `-o` option but doesn't support `-P`. Good catch though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when there was no match, `$score` is then the empty string.

A simple fix:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls $1/*.html`
do
        score=`grep -o -P '(?<=ADJ. SCORE: )-?[0-9]?[0-9]' $f`
        if [ -z $score ]
        then
            echo "No match in '$f'"
        else
            if [ "$score" -lt 36 ]
            then 
                cp "$f" "$2"
            fi
        fi
done
```

I think you also need to be more aware of *quoting* requirements in shell scripting.

Comment: Thanks Sehe, this did the trick! And thanks for the advice on the quoting.

Answer (score 1):

sehe is right,
Or you can do:

```
if [[ $score < 36 ]]
then
cp "$f" "$2"
fi
```

Comment: Sure. It's just another way to do it. More info is [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) towards the middle of the page. To read more about the [[..]] construct, [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS)

Answer (score 0):

On my mac running Mountain Lion version 10.8.4 I don't see `-P` option with `grep`. So you can use `perl` for instead (re-using most of your script):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "${1}"/*.html; do    # Don't parse ls
  score=$(perl -ne "print $& if /(?<=ADJ. SCORE: )-?[0-9]?[0-9]/" "$f")
  if [ "$score" -lt 36 ]; then 
    cp "$f" $2
  fi
done
```

Comment: I've had a lot of troubles using regex with grep on 10.7 and found that the -P flag makes it work. I've read in some old forum threads that Apple hasn't been using a consistent version of grep, which may be part of the problem.

From my manual: 
`       -P, --perl-regexp`
`              Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is  highly  experimental  and  grep  -P  may  warn  of unimplemented features.`

Comment: Oh, also: I'm using GNU Grep 2.14, which I might have installed using MacPorts a while back to deal with another project.